# Windows Azure Mobile Services REST API documentation

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

Is there any management API in Windows Azure Mobile Services? For example: methods to create mobile services or data tables. I could not find any documentation. I have read in some other thread that the API is available but not available publicly. Any expectation about its availability.

Answer (score 2):

There is no REST API for ***managing*** Windows Azure Mobile Services, for operations like you mentioned (creating / configuring services; creating / configuring tables; etc). If you want to script those operations you can use the [Azure command-line interface](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/xplat-cli/) - that will let you perform those operations in the command line (for example via a batch / shell / command line script). That tool is implemented in node.js, so you can also use it in a node.js application, by using the [azure-cli package](https://www.npmjs.org/package/azure-cli).

There is a REST API for ***using*** a specific Azure Mobile Service - and you can find the documentation for it at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj710108.aspx.

Comment: Is there any future plan of Azure Team for providing a 'managing' option by REST API like other services in Management REST API?

Comment: I don't know of the plans, but you can create a feature request under http://feedback.windowsazure.com/forums/216254-mobile-services (or vote up for one if it already exists) for this.

Comment: Can you perform the operation by calling node.js operation form c# application?

Comment: I'd guess it's possible, if from the C# app you'd start a new process which would invoke node.exe to use it. I haven't tried it, though.

Comment: I have been able to execute the node script from my local machine for creation of mobile web services. Now I am going to delopy my C# in Window Azure cloud. Would I be able to execute the same scripts from azure clound deployment. My local machine is having the node package install and want to know either I need to install the package on cloud too